# On a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, is it true for any $2$-form $\mu$, that $\mu=0$ iff $\omega^{n-1}\wedge\mu=0$?

Tags: differential-forms, symplectic-geometry

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1009.1175.pdf), on page 8 (above Theorem 9), I found the following claim::

> Let $(M,\omega)$ be a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold. If $\mu$ is any $2$-form on $M$, then $$\omega^{n-1}\wedge\mu=0\Leftrightarrow \mu=0.$$

The implication $\Leftarrow$ is clear, but I have trouble understanding why the other implication holds. Could somebody shine some light on this?

Comment: Is there a missing hypothesis? Take $M=\Bbb{R}^4$, $\omega=dx_1 \wedge dx_2 + dx_3 \wedge dx_4$, $\mu = dx_1 \wedge dx_3$. But this counterexample doesn't seem to generalize to higher dimensions, so it could very well be true there...

Comment: @Micah There are no extra hypotheses. It seems to me that your counter example is valid in general $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$: if $\omega=\sum_{i=1}^{n}dx_{i}\wedge dy_{i}$ then $\omega^{n-1}=(n-1)!\sum_{i=1}^{n}\omega_{i}$ where $\omega_{i}$ is $dx_{1}\wedge dy_{1}\wedge\cdots\wedge dx_{n}\wedge dy_{n}$  with $dx_{i}\wedge dy_{i}$  omitted. So $\mu=dx_{1}\wedge dx_{2}$ will again do the job. Strange.

Comment: You're absolutely right; I was confusing myself.

Comment: @Studiosus, in your comment, the last equation should be $\mu=dx_1\wedge dx_3$.

Comment: @Micah You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a mistake in the paper, as the counterexamples in the comments section demonstrate.